# Password type gets toggled to Text on clicking Show Password but the the password is not visible

Tags: javascript, html

In my test php file, I have added the below code. I have 4 password type fields. I have added a 'Show Password' checkbox to each of these password fields.
I have tried to reuse the onclick function to toggle between types 'password' and 'text'. But then this does not work for the first 3 fields. The 4th field, on clicking 'Show Password' the type changes to 'Text' and on unchecking, the type goes back to 'Password' type.

I dont seem to find the reason why it is working only for the 4th password field and not the first 3 password fields.

```
    <p>
    <input type="password" name="psw2" id="2"><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="showPassword3" onclick="myFunction2('2')">Show Password
    </p>
    <br>
    working and original field<br>
    <input type="password" name="psw3" id="mutatePasswdField"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="showPassword4" onclick="myFunction2('mutatePasswdField')">Show Password
    bug<br>
    <input type="password" name="psw4" id="1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="showPassword5" onclick="myFunction2('1')">Show Password
    bug<br>
    <input type="password" name="psw5" id="password7"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="showPassword6" onclick="myFunction2('password7')">Show Password


<script>
function myFunction2(id) {
  var y = document.getElementById(id);
  if (y.type === "password") {
    y.type = "text";
  } else {
    y.type = "password";
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your is working properly,you may check it from the following URL:
https://jsfiddle.net/jh92fesr/

Comment: Thank you @TheKNVB. Thanks for the URL. I see it works here. For some strange reason it does not work in my demopage. Guess it's something local on my page.

Comment: Maybe you can press "F12" to view the error message in the console.

Comment: Thanks again @TheKNVB It was a silly mistake. There were elements having the same id as the 3 password fields which was causing the issue.